# Function to get a value from table if not empry else generate new value

Tags: postgresql

```
create sequence number_generator as int;

create table my_numbers (
    num int primary key;
);
```

How to implement a function with the following logic:

if *my_numbers* is not empty then
    delete one row and return the deleted number
else
    return next value from the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from my_numbers 
  where num in (select min(num) from my_numbers)
  returning num
)
select num
from deleted
union all
select nextval('number_generator')
where not exists (select * from deleted);
```

First the row with the lowest num is deleted, and the deleted number is returned. The final select returns either that number or calls `nextval()` but only if no row was returned from the delete statement.

---

To put that into a function use:

```sql
create or replace function delete_or_get()
  returns bigint
as
$$
with deleted as (
  delete from my_numbers 
  where num in (select min(num) from my_numbers)
  returning num
)
select num
from deleted
union all
select nextval('number_generator')
where not exists (select * from deleted);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: @quantum_well: sure, that's possible

Comment: I meant could you make it into function. Somehow I can't it working as a function.